# The proper way to write a SharePoint User to a User Field in a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, csom, sharepoint-online

I'm writing a user to a SharePoint list.

I've read that the SharePoint User field has a string like this inside of it:
`userId;#userLoginName`

I've tried formatting in the same way when writing to a User field, for example when I write this string it works:
`9;#i:0#.f|membership|ectropy@example.org`

But what is strange (to me at least) is that `9;#` seems to work or even `9`. Even if I don't pass the `userLoginName` info at all, the `loginId` seems to be enough for it to recognize which User I'm talking about.

This seems to imply that when writing to the SharePoint User field, you only need the id, and the `userLoginName`, or, indeed, everything after the `loginId` is irrelevant.

Am I correct in my reasoning here? Or perhaps there's unexpected consequences if I leave off the userLoginName information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, only User Id is a mandatory property when specifying value for a User field.

But since [SP.FieldUserValue object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246963%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is used to store value of User field, it is recommended to get and set values using this object as demonstrated in the below example:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var lists = web.get_lists();
var list = lists.getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(itemId);

var assignedToVal = new SP.FieldUserValue();
assignedToVal.set_lookupId(11);   //specify User Id 
item.set_item(fieldName,assignedToVal);
item.update();

ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
        console.log('Updated');
    },
    function(sender,args) {
        console.log('An error occurred:' + args.get_message());
    }
);
```

Comment: Ok perfect, so rather than just doing `newItem.set_item('Manager', "9");` (which is how my current code works) it would be better to do `var assignedToVal = new SP.FieldUserValue(); assignedToVal.set_lookupId(9); item.set_item(fieldName,assignedToVal);` if I'm following correctly.

Comment: If user is of type SP.FieldUserValue then user.get_id() returns the UserId

Comment: Do not forget to load the sp.js `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', loadSPContext);`

Answer (score 0):

I find answer here using the person name instead the id  is more easy than find user id 
if you dont have it.

https://gist.github.com/rheid/18635032d8371c7825b3320eae57071f

```
// Single Person  
   var singleUser = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser('Peter Dotsenko');  
   oListItem.set_item('PetkaPersonSingle', singleUser);  

   //Multi Person  
   var petkaUserMultiArray = new Array("peterd@domain.com","Peter Dotsenko","domain\\peterd");  
   var lookups = [];  
   for (var ii in petkaUserMultiArray) {  
      var lookupValue = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(petkaUserMultiArray[ii]);  
      lookups.push(lookupValue);  
   }  
   oListItem.set_item('PetkaPersonMulti', lookups);
//
```