# Inserting a user into a person field in sharepoint using the rest api

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to update a list item in a remote sharepoint site using the rest api from a workflow.  I'm having issues understanding how to populate a person field.  I've looked online and read that you should use the id of the user and not the login, however what if I do not know the users id?  Where can I get this from?

I've been reading the following link but it doesn't explain where the id comes from

[how to add user to sharepoint list item user field using REST api in sp2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500077/how-to-add-user-to-sharepoint-list-item-user-field-using-rest-api-in-sp2013)

Comment: Are you working with javascript or c#? Maybe this helps: [Get User Info via Rest](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to view all UserProfile Properties by using this REST call:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\user'
```

To get a specific Property (in this case UserProfileGUID) use:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='UserProfile_GUID')?@v='domain\user'
```

If you are using CSOM this might help you:
[The proper way to write a SharePoint User to a User Field in a SharePoint list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271440/the-proper-way-to-write-a-sharepoint-user-to-a-user-field-in-a-sharepoint-list)

I have done this successfully in the past using both CSOM (js) and SSOM (powershell).

Answer (score 0):

I know its a a bit late but for anyone looking for the answer on how to get the user id use the below function

```html
function getUserId(userName) {

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id&$filter=Title eq '" + userName + "'",
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            return data.d.results[0].Id;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```